# Auto tag list for new comers even before typing

Tags: feature-request, tags

Many times it has happened to me that I wanted to a ask a question on one of the SO sites, but even though being clear about what I wanted to ask, wasn't really sure which tags would be useful for my problem. This happened especially when I wasn't a regular to that particular site or I was a newbie.

Wouldn't it be good if there is an option for people [specially *newcomers* (time based/reputation based)]

1. To help them just auto fill the tags
2. or at least provide them suggestions if they want, *even if they haven't typed anything*

I think by parsing their problem statement and some fair amount of AI it would be possible? 
May be it's personal, but I just find it difficult sometimes to fill in the minimum required tags.

PS: And now I am finding it difficult to give a tag to this problem itself. I had to look into the tags to actually find something.

Comment: I think it is OK for the tag to be incorrect. Experienced user can go and fix the tags. The new user will learn from it - if they continue to use the site.

Comment: Interesting machine learning problem. Mainstream language tags [seems easy enough](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.12.4776) but for more obscure tags it gets harder. You might be able to do something with some off-line feature selection but that'd be quite slow for 3,000,000 examples and you risk selecting irrelevant traits (e.g. if capitalization of words is poor then it's more likely to be tag X). (Note: this is [in the job description](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/19463/stack-exchange-search-architect-stack-exchange) of a vacant post)